# I stand corrected vs I stand to be corrected

Tags: expressions

What's the difference between "**I stand corrected**." and "**I stand to be corrected**."?

Comment: The latter hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 3):

"**I stand corrected**." = I was wrong and this has been demonstrated by what has been said/done.

> 1955: Care of Alaskan Mentally Ill: Hearings Before the United States House ...
> By United States Congress House Committee) *Mr ABBOTT: I believe you stated earlier your bond was in the amount of $15,000. The contract entered into the 18th day of June
> 1953 indicates it to be $30,000.*
>
> *Mr. Wanye W. Coe: Well then, **I stand corrected. I stand corrected**."*

and

**"I stand to be corrected"** = I may be wrong (i) and I would be interested to hear if anyone has another idea. (ii) and future events may demonstrate this.

> 2004 Nomination of the Honorable Porter J. Goss to be Director of Central ...
> By United States, United States. Congress. *Senator Kery proposed a $45 billion cut aimed at science, intelligence and defense projects within Committee. Basically, he decided when that became stalled that he would then go to the floor—if I have this right, and **I stand to be corrected** —and propose a $6 billion cut, a targeted cut, at intelligence, as opposed to an across-the-board cut.*

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked on [this forum](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/147401-quot-I-stand-corrected-quot-and-quot-I-stand-to-be-corrected-quot).

Here is a brief summary of the thread which answers your question:

"I stand corrected" is usually the more common expression.

"I stand to be corrected." means this according to a person on this forum:

> It's a quick way of saying 'I might be wrong about that statement I have just made and feel sure somebody will put me right if that is the case'.

I hope this answers your question.